# JTwain API is not working for some scanners on particular machines

Tags: java, twain, image-scanner

I am using JTwain API to connect to scanners from my java web application. However it is not working for some of scanners. Now i am worried whether my code have some bug or some certain scanners are not compatible with JTwain API.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to verify what protocol JTwain supports and whether your scanners have the corresponding driver. If it is TWAIN, you can use [Twacker](http://www.twain.org/scannerdriverdevelopers/specification-and-tools.html) provided by the TWAIN Working Group to verify it.

Answer (score 0):

The vendor of JTwain has release a successor, [Java Scanning & Imaging SDK, which allows you to do Java document scanning from TWAIN WIA scanners](http://asprise.com/document-scanner-image-pdf/java-scanning-api-overview.html) for both 64bit and 32bit JVMs.

> [Asprise Scanning and Imaging SDK](http://asprise.com/document-scanner-image-pdf/java-scanning-api-overview.html) offers a high performance API library
>   so that you can acquire images from and have total control on almost
>   all kinds of TWAIN WIA scanners on Windows 32bit/64bit and Mac OS X.
>   With the SDK's powerful and flexible API, you can equip your Java
>   applications (Java applets, web applications, Swing/JavaFX components,
>   JEE enterprise applications) with functionality of high speed document
>   scanning (e.g., ADF bulk scan to multi-page PDF) and image
>   acquisition. You can rest assured that the SDK is fully compliant with
>   various government privacy acts such as HIPPA and HITECH.

Most scanners are supported by Asprise Java Scanning SDK: Acer, AGFA, Brother, Canon, Dell, Epson, Fujitsu, HP, IBM, Kodak, Konica Minolta, Lexmark, NEC, Nikon, Olympus, Panasonic, Ricoh, Samsung, Xerox and many more TWAIN WIA scanners and cameras.

Answer (score -1):

There is a 30 days trial for this software. After the 30 days you need to buy to licenses. (5K)